# Searching for a sawfish config

Tags: configuration, sawfish

On the [Sawfish Wikia](http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Screenshots), there's a beautiful image:

[image]

Does anyone know how to configure sawfish to look like this? I can't find any docs regarding this picture/desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His `sawfish.rc` is on github here: https://github.com/ZaneA/Dotfiles/blob/master/rc

and there are links to the GTK theme and sawfish theme in that screenshot on his deviantart page here: http://hashbox.deviantart.com/art/Arch-170211-197724511

Comment: so e.g.: after an ubuntu minimal install i just apt-get install sawfish, then echo "xinit /usr/bin/sawfish" >> /home/USERNAME/.bashrc then log off, log in, then sawfish starts, ok, then i just put the code from github to the ~/.sawfish/rc file then install theme, then presto? :P

Comment: I've not used sawfish, so I don't know. There is a wiki that seems to have all of that sort of information: http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Putting xinit into `~/.bashrc` sounds like a very, very bad idea given that that file is sourced every time you open a terminal window...

Comment: then where to put "xinit /usr/bin/sawfish" ? :P thanks for the warning..

Comment: If you are using it as a standalone window manager, then create an `.xinitrc` file. See the wiki http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/User_Guide